# OnDraw bug in android 4.2

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I have downloaded the 4.2 image for tests and I'm surprised with one thing. I have a HorizontalScrollView filled by ImageView's ancestors in my application. I rely on the fact, that onDraw in these ImageViews is called only when the view becomes explicitly visible to a user. But what I'm observing in 4.2 is that onDraw is called just at the moment of adding views to the HorizontalScrollView. Is it a supposed behaviour? Or am I missing anything?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `onDraw` is called when the view has been inflated and after its measured.

I would never assume that `onDraw` means that that view is visible to a user. Even the `onDisplayHint` is not assurance that the view is visible.

Also worth noting the `onDraw` can be called multiple times, as other views move or the `View` hierarchy is `invalidated()`.

Hope that helps?

If not have a good read through - [Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)